# How do i completely wipe all of my disks with a dual boot

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, multi-boot, formatting

I want to completely reset my PC, i have 3 drives, two HDDs and an SSD. I have Windows installed on the SSD and Ubuntu on a Partition of the smaller HDD.

I guess I would just format the two hdds first. But how do I completely format the drive on wich windows is installed, can I just use Windows Explorer to do it?

Should i format the hdds and then remove them from my pc before installing the new Windows ?

Comment: Ensure you have all non-generic device drivers before starting.

Comment: @harrymc can you explain further, i dont understand

Comment: I have added an answer. This procedure is longer than just popping in the boot DVD, but with it you can resolve all eventual problems.

Comment: @harrymc thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before installing Windows, beware of devices you might have for which the Windows
installation might lack drivers.

For a safe installation, better follow these instructions:

- Ensure that you have all the installation media for all your
  installed products and their serial keys (if any).
  Windows 10 does not require a serial key if it has been once activated on this
  computer.
- Backup all your drivers using one of the products from the article
  [Best Free Windows Driver Backup and Restore](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-windows-driver-backup.htm)
- Take an image backup of the system disk using a product such as
  [AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html),
  make a
  [bootable media](https://www.backup-utility.com/features/create-bootable-disc.html),
  and test booting it to see that it can see both the hard disk and the
  backup image, just in case you will want to restore the last working
  version of Windows.
- [Reset](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026528/windows-10-reset-or-reinstall)
  might be safer than installing from the Windows boot media, but ensure that
  you have that media at hand before starting.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to install a new OS in the section about selecting a partition for installation you should have the option to erase any and all drives.

Comment: So format the two HDDs and then reinstall windows and use that option ?